# Why is lazy loading so slow in my table when in editing mode?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Table with 15 columns and about 4000 rows in total. I need to make some of the columns editable so I am using a TableFieldFactory for this.

The problem is that when I go into editing mode, things load REALLY slow. When I scroll down and the lazy loading loads another buffer, it can take up to 20 seconds before the table is repainted.

Even when only having one column editable, it loads unbearably slow.

```
@Override
public Field<?> createField(Container container, Object itemId, Object propertyId, com.vaadin.ui.Component uiContext) {

    TextField tField = (TextField) DefaultFieldFactory.get().createField(container, itemId, propertyId, uiContext);
    tField.setImmediate(true);

    if (propertyId.equals("Foo") {
        return tField;
    }
    else {
        tField.setReadOnly(true);
    }

    return tField;
}
```

In one lazy loading, about 500-1000 rows are loaded, so createField() is called maybe 7500-15000 times, but is this a known limitation of Vaadin or am I doing something wrong? Maybe I shouldn't be using TableFieldFactory in the first place, when having so many columns?

Does anyone know if there is a better way of implementing the mentioned table, without getting these crazy buffer loading times?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "one row editable" - are you still creating a read-only field (as in your quoted code above)?

Don't.

Return null from the FieldFactory (and also, for non-"Foo" fields). Only return a field from the Field factory if you want the column to be editable: if not, return null.

There's a big difference between no field and and a read-only field: Without a field (or a field factory), Vaadin will simply generate a very simple `<div>` with no listeners or anything else. As soon as you start having many components in a large Vaadin table, you are going to see some kind of performance degradation.

So - firstly, I would change your field factory to the following.

```
@Override
public Field<?> createField(Container container, Object itemId, Object propertyId, com.vaadin.ui.Component uiContext) {

 if (propertyId.equals("Foo") {
   TextField tField = (TextField) DefaultFieldFactory.get().createField(container, itemId, propertyId, uiContext);
   tField.setImmediate(true);

   return tField;
 }

 return null;
}
```

If that doesn't make a big enough difference,  I would then change the factory to only create fields for the currently selected row.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant column, not row.

Comment: I think the answer still holds. A read-only field != no field at all!

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just tried this and it became *better*, but alas, as I add editable columns to the table the rendering becomes slower. I need a total of 7 editable columns in my table, and two of them are DateFields. The 5 TextField columns load in about 5 secs per buffer now, which is an improvement, but the two DateField columns alone takes at least the same to load, so I'm still on at least a 10 second loading time for each buffer, returning null on each field that is not editable.

Comment: So, the follow up question would be - Am I pushing the envelope now for what is reasonable to expect from a Vaadin Table performance wise, the way I implemented things? If so, your answer is completely valid!

Comment: Myself - I would only generate fields for one row at a time (i.e. the selected row), as in my example from yesterday. With your 500-1000 rows per lazy load, you are still talking 7x500 (or1000)=3500-7000 fields being attached to the DOM at the same time. That's way too many to be performant.

Comment: Of course. I haven't had time to look at your git implementation for the other issue. It's so obvious now that you mentioned the null return. For some reason I locked my mind on that the table *had* to return a field. The loading is now considerably faster, even with 7 editable columns. I can actually edit at least 20 rows at one time without being too bothered about the loading process! Why I have to edit more than one row at one time is another question that has to do with the users way of work. Thanks a bunch, Charles!